# How to obtain a specific person's tweets in a specific time interval (Twitter4J)?

Tags: filter, twitter4j

I want to collect some specific people's tweets in recent one year. I'm using Twitter4J, like this:

```
Paging paging = new Paging(i, 200);
    try {
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("martinsuchan",paging);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But how can I filter the Tweets of that user for a certain time interval?

Any answer appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the statuses locally, based on `status.getCreatedAt()`. Example:

```
try {
    int statusesPerPage = 200;
    int page = 1;
    String username = "username";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    Paging paging = new Paging(page, statusesPerPage);
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(username, paging);

    page_loop:
    while (statuses.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Showing @" + username + "'s home timeline, page " + page);
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            if (status.getCreatedAt().before(cal.getTime())) {
                break page_loop;
            }
            System.out.println(status.getCreatedAt() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        paging = new Paging(++page, statusesPerPage);
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(username, paging);
    }
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think serach/tweets endpoint don't return tweets for a year. You should use statuses/user_timeline endpoint https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: @aalazz,@itzmukeshy Thank you all, I will try those mehtods. I used put status and it's created time together, and then filter those Strings by time tag ,but I don't think it's a good solution. Thank you all.